# Elements of order $18$ from $Z_{12}×Z_{9}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have to find elements of order $18$ from $Z_{12}×Z_{9}$.
I did the following thing:
The order of the elements in $Z_{12}$ must be ${1,2,3,4,6,12}$ and the order of elements in $Z_9$ must be $1,3,9$. I have to find elements $(a,b) ∈ Z_{12}×Z_{9}$ so that the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$ in $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{9}$ respectively is $18$, but there are no such order numbers in $Z_{12}$ and $Z_9$ that the least common multiple is $18$.

Does that mean that they don't exist, or am I missing something ?

*Edit*: I didn't see order $9$ elements in $Z_{9}$

Comment: What about the elements of order $9$ in $Z_9$?

Comment: ahh yeah, I forgot all about order $9$ in $Z_9$ and $12$ in $Z_{12}$, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This is mechanized in Maple.  Maple finds these elements explicitly.

Comment: @user64494 how do I do this in maple ?

Comment: How about $(6,1)$

Comment: well $(6,1) = 6$ not $18$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have determined the lists  $\ell:=\{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$ and $\ell':=\{1,3,9\}$ of the divisors of $12$ and $9$. If $a\in{\mathbb Z}_{12}$ has order $d\in\ell$ and $b\in{\mathbb Z}_9$ has order $d'\in\ell'$ then $(a,b)$ has order $n:={\rm lcm}(d,d')$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{12}\times{\mathbb Z}_9$. Since we want $n=18$ we have to determine the pairs $(d,d')\in\ell\times\ell'$ with this property. There are two such pairs, namely $(2,9)$ and $(6,9)$.

There is exactly one element of order $d=2$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{12}$, namely $6$. On the other hand all elements $j\in{\mathbb Z}_9$ with ${\rm gcd}(j,9)=1$ have order $d'=9$. These are the six elements $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm4$. It follows that $(d,d')=(2,9)$ leads to the following six elements of order $18$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{12}\times{\mathbb Z}_9$:
$$(6,\pm1),\quad (6,\pm2),\quad (6,\pm 4)\ .$$

We now have to determine the elements of order $d=6$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{12}$. An element $j\in{\mathbb Z}_{12}$ has order $6$ iff $6j=0$ mod $12$, but $r j\ne0$ mod $12$ for $1\leq r\leq 5$. It follows that $j$ has to be even, but not divisible by $4$ or $6$.  Therefore the only elements of order $6$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{12}$ are $\pm2$. The conclusion is that $(d,d')=(6,9)$ leads to the following $12$ elements of order $18$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{12}\times{\mathbb Z}_9$:
$$(\pm2,\pm1),\quad (\pm2,\pm2),\quad (\pm2,\pm 4)\ ,$$
whereby the signs can be chosen independently.

Comment: amazing explication, I understood everything, thank you so much for the time to answer this impeccably! +1

Comment: Hello! I tried to do it another way; I wrote $Z_{12} \times Z_9$ as $Z_4 \times Z_9 \times Z_3$. Now consider an element $(a, b, c)$ of order $18$. We have only one choice for $a$. For $b$, we have $6-1=5$ choices. For $c$, we have $3$ choices, so this gives me $15$ choices. But this seems to disagree with your answer of $12$. Would you happen to know why this method fails?

Comment: @Blue: For $b$ you have the $6$ choices $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm4$, so that you obtain $1\cdot6\cdot3=18$ admissible triples, coinciding with my $18$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Ah yes thank you!